# Forcing a TLS 1.0 POST request with Requests

Tags: python-requests, python-3.8, pyopenssl, tls1.0

To start I know that TLSv1.0 is super old and should not be used, but I need to connect to some really old local hardware that isn't supporting anything else atm

```
#import ssl
from OpenSSL import SSL

try:
    import urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl
    urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl.inject_into_urllib3()
except ImportError:
    pass

import requests sys, os, select, socket

from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.poolmanager import PoolManager
from requests.packages.urllib3.util import ssl_
from requests.packages.urllib3.contrib import py

CIPHERS = (
    'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:
    ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:'
)

class TlsAdapter(HTTPAdapter):

    def __init__(self, ssl_options=0, **kwargs):
        self.ssl_options = ssl_options
        super(TlsAdapter, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def init_poolmanager(self, *pool_args, **pool_kwargs):
        ctx = SSL.Context(SSL.TLSv1_METHOD)
        self.poolmanager = PoolManager(*pool_args,
                                       ssl_context=ctx,
                                       **pool_kwargs)

session = requests.Session()
adapter = TlsAdapter(ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1 | ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_2)
session.mount("https://", adapter)

data = { "key":"value"}
try:
    r = session.post("https://192.168.1.1", data)
    print(r)
except Exception as exception:
    print(exception)
```

I've tried several ways. The above code is mostly ripped from similar issues posted here in the past but python3 ssl no longer supports TLSv1 so it throws an unsupported protocol error. I added the "import urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl" to try and force it to use pyOpenSSL instead per this urllib3 documentation. The current error with this code is
`load_verify_locations() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given`
I know this is from the verify part of urllib3 context and I need to fix the context for pyOpenSSL but I've been stuck here trying to fix the context.

Answer (score 0):

Analyzed the website in question in "https://www.ssllabs.com/" , the simulator doesn't use python for testing. I haven't been successful using python. However with jdk 1.8 , I was able to comment the line in the security file as mentioned in "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xSejtYOh4C0" and was able to work around the issue.

The server prefers these cipher suites. Is these supported ciphers in urllib3 ?

TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 (0x4)   INSECURE   128
TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0x5)   INSECURE   128
TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xa)   WEAK

Right now I'm stuck with the below error:

*urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='{}', port={}): Max retries exceeded with url: /xxx.htm (Caused by ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory')))*